# How to Break Array into Smaller Arrays?

Tags: php, regex

I need to break an array into smaller arrays using a deliminator such as a space, not using a certain numbers of chars (therefore array_chunk will not work for this and these answers [How to break an array into a specified number of smaller arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4596900/php-how-to-break-an-array-into-a-specified-number-of-smaller-arrays) is not relevant for the same reason).

Example:

```
$array1 = ("One two three","four five six","seven eight nine");
```

Would like to split "One two three" into three elements in one array (using a space as deliminator) and the same for the next two elements. This can be split  into multidimensional
array as well.

Comment: Post an example of what kind of input you're expecting to get, and what you want the output to be.

Comment: And why do you think this is best done with regexes?

Comment: Bec I need to match complex patterns not just a space.

Comment: What delimiters do you need?

Comment: EITHER  a space or a comma (any two words basically)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
php> $array1 = array("One two three","four five six","seven eight nine");

php> =array_map(function($a){return explode(' ',$a);},$array1)
array(
  0 => array(
    0 => "One",
    1 => "two",
    2 => "three",
  ),
  1 => array(
    0 => "four",
    1 => "five",
    2 => "six",
  ),
  2 => array(
    0 => "seven",
    1 => "eight",
    2 => "nine",
  ),
)
```

The anonymous function can be changed to however you see fit. Regex, whatever.

**edit** Per your comments:

```
php> $array1 = array("One two three","four five,six","seven,eight nine");

php> =array_map(function($a){return preg_split('/[ ,]/',$a);},$array1)
array(
  0 => array(
    0 => "One",
    1 => "two",
    2 => "three",
  ),
  1 => array(
    0 => "four",
    1 => "five",
    2 => "six",
  ),
  2 => array(
    0 => "seven",
    1 => "eight",
    2 => "nine",
  ),
)
```

Comment: Yes, the OP is asking what function can do regex split, for which `preg_split` should be the answer.
http://au1.php.net/preg_split

Comment: I don't see that in the Q

Comment: ^^ No, you did not understand the question (justhalf)

Comment: a space or a comma is not actually a complex pattern, haha